# I want to Print multiple lines of Text using a JTextPane to a window

Tags: java, user-interface, text, window, jtextpane

I've search this question in different wording for the past day or two now and I just can not solve it :/,

I have Window that pops up on the screen that looks like a Command Prompt there is a two buttons Run and Stop. Anyways I have on the screen once you press start it starts "Scanning files" It says "Scanning 1-1900 something" counts up to 1900 and then says Scan completed, after that I want text to go Under the existing Text
and write multiple lines of text to mess with my friend for example.

```
{
Scan Completed
"wait time inbetween each line of text"
Hack initialized
"wait time inbetween each line of text"
Hack installing...
"wait time inbetween each line of text"
Hack installed
ECT
}
```

Hopefully someone can Help me, every one I looked at did not work with my code :/
I'm new to code as well so...

thanks in advance anyways here my code its not to long :P.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Happy Monday v0.05");
        Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();

        JTextPane jta = new JTextPane();

        JButton button = new JButton("Run");
        JButton buttonstop = new JButton("Stop"); 

        contentPane.add(button);
        contentPane.add(buttonstop);  

        button.setBounds(-1,283,465,40);
        buttonstop.setBounds(465,283,469,40);

        frame.add(jta).setBackground(Color.black);
        console(jta);

        //Window        
        frame.setSize(950, 650 / 16 * 9);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                new SwingWorker<Void, Object>(){
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        outputTest("Scanning...");
                        return null;

                    }}.execute();
            }});

    }

    //Testing OUTPUTS:/
    public static void outputTest(String msg){
        for(int i=0;i<1969;i++){
            System.out.println(i+" "+msg);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(01);
                System.out.println("Scan Complete");

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
    }

    public static void console(final JTextPane area) throws IOException {
        area.setContentType("text/html");
        final PipedInputStream outPipe = new PipedInputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new PipedOutputStream(outPipe), true));       
        new SwingWorker<Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                Scanner s = new Scanner(outPipe);
                while (s.hasNextLine()){
                    String line = s.nextLine();
                    publish(line + "\n");
                }
                return null;
            }
            @Override
            protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
                for (String line : chunks){
                    area.setText("<font size=\"5\" color=\"green\">"+line+"</font>");
                    }   
                 }
        }.execute();
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add details of what you code does now. Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

The `setText` method does not appends the line.It overrides the text.So previous text won't be visible.

You have to append text, but have to find an mechanism for that as append method do not exist. In your console method, you can add these:

```
Document doc = area.getDocument();
Thread.sleep(2000);
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),"hack installing....\n", null);
Thread.sleep(2000);
doc.insertString(doc.getLength(),"Hack installed...\n", null);
```

**Note:**

Calling `Thread.sleep()` is not recommended directly as you are using multi-threaded environment.It's just for your example haven't scanned your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NotEditableOutputArea extends JTextPane {

        public NotEditableOutputArea() {
            setEditable(false);
            DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) getCaret();
            caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);
            Font defaultFont = new Font("monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 12);
            setFont(defaultFont);
        }

        public void appendColorText(String text, Color c) {
            StyledDocument doc = getStyledDocument();
            Style style = addStyle("Style", null);
            StyleConstants.setForeground(style, c);
            try {
                doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, style);
            } catch (BadLocationException e) {
            }

        }

        public void setColorText(String text, Color c) {
            setText(null);
            appendColorText(text, c);
        }
    }
```

Comment: please atleast explain your solution a bit, like small explainable comments on each of the methods implemented